# Is there a more elegant way in PHP to parse this xpath object?

Tags: php, xpath

I am parsing the XML returned from Google Map API V3. Here is the typical XML returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"><Response>
  <name>40.74445606,-73.97495072</name>
  <Status>
    <code>200</code>
    <request>geocode</request>
  </Status>
  <Placemark id="p1">
    <address>317 E 34th St, New York, NY 10016, USA</address>
    <AddressDetails Accuracy="8" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0"><Country><CountryNameCode>US</CountryNameCode><CountryName>USA</CountryName><AdministrativeArea><AdministrativeAreaName>NY</AdministrativeAreaName><Locality><LocalityName>New York</LocalityName><Thoroughfare><ThoroughfareName>317 E 34th St</ThoroughfareName></Thoroughfare><PostalCode><PostalCodeNumber>10016</PostalCodeNumber></PostalCode></Locality></AdministrativeArea></Country></AddressDetails>
    <ExtendedData>
      <LatLonBox north="40.7458050" south="40.7431070" east="-73.9736017" west="-73.9762997" />
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point><coordinates>-73.9749507,40.7444560,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
</Response></kml>
```

Here is a fragment of the PHP code I'm using to parse it:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('http', 'http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0');
$LatLonBox_result = $xml->xpath('//http:LatLonBox');

echo "North: " . $LatLonBox_result[0]["north"] . "\n";
echo "South: " . $LatLonBox_result[0]["south"] . "\n";
echo "East: " . $LatLonBox_result[0]["east"] . "\n";
echo "West: " . $LatLonBox_result[0]["west"] . "\n";

var_dump($LatLonBox_result);
```

Here is the edited output:

```
North: 40.7458050
South: 40.7431070
East: -73.9736017
West: -73.9762997
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["north"]=>
      string(10) "40.7458050"
      ["south"]=>
      string(10) "40.7431070"
      ["east"]=>
      string(11) "-73.9736017"
      ["west"]=>
      string(11) "-73.9762997"
    }
  }
}
```

Using $LatLonBox_result[0]["north"] seems ugly looking to me. Is this just how things are when working with xpath? I was expecting a returned value perhaps something like $LatLonBox_result["north"] and not have the first dimension of the array. Or is this approach wrong? 
If there is a better way to do this, please kindly enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: Nope thats it... xpath always returns an array, even if there is only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath` returns *always* an **array** (in fact you are getting the first element of it) with the results found (regardless they are only one or more), or `FALSE` in case of error.

I think your code is just fine, except for being not very robust. You better check the result with `empty($result)` before doing anything else with it.

```
$LatLonBox_result = $xml->xpath('//http:LatLonBox');

if (!empty($LatLonBox_result)) {
    echo "North: " . $LatLonBox_result[0]["north"] . "\n";
    echo "South: " . $LatLonBox_result[0]["south"] . "\n";
    echo "East: " . $LatLonBox_result[0]["east"] . "\n";
    echo "West: " . $LatLonBox_result[0]["west"] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer, example code and the attention to detail to make it more robust. I thought I was doing this incorrectly. Thanks!